How exactly does early stopping work with XGBoost CV in Python?
My understanding of cross-validation is that training data is divided into n folds. For each fold, a model is trained on all other folds and validated on the selected fold. At the end, we will have n models and n validation results. We average these results out to get the cross-validation test result.
What I don't understand is how will this work with early stopping. If I set early stopping criteria, each model training in cross-validation may stop at a different boosting round due to variations in data.
Let's say if we do a 5-fold cv. What would happen if the 5 models stopped at boosting rounds 20, 17, 25, 27, 30 respectively due to early stopping? As we know the returned cv_results dataframe shows the average train and test metrics of each boosting round. How would it handle this case?
How do I get the best number of boosting rounds from this cross-validation?
